# Why is there no such file or directory of my react app?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, terminal, directory

I created a React App with the terminal command npx create-react-app and called it fb-clone. Now when I try to cd or ls into the directory called fb-clone, it says in the terminal "no such file or directory: fb-clone/".

Terminal looks something like this:

```
ls
fb-clone/
*then I get the error*
```

then I try:

```
cd fb-clone/
*then I get another error*
```

Comment: You ran only `npx create-react-app`? How did you provide `fb-clone` name?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I ran npx create-react-app my-app <--- named fb-clone

Comment: You can run `ls` to see all the files in the folder you're currently in